# Why isn't my PHP program working?

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner at PHP and I wrote a code to justify a piece of text in the Google Chrome browser. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Justification with PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Text Justification with PHP</h1>
<?php
$myText = <<<END_TEXT
But think not that this famous town has
only harpooneers, cannibals, and
bumpkins to show her visitors. Not at
all. Still New Bedford is a queer place.
Had it not been for us whalemen, that
tract of land would this day perhaps
have been in as howling condition as the
coast of Labrador.

END_TEXT;
$lineLength = 40;
$myText = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $myText);
$myTextJustified = "";
$numLines = substr_count($myText, "\n");
$startOfLine = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $numLines; $i++){
    $originalLineLength = strpos($myText, "\n", $startOfLine) - $startOfLine;
    $justifiedLine = substr($myText, $startOfLine, $originalLineLength);
    $justifiedLineLength = $originalLineLength;

    while ($i < $numLines - 1 && $justifiedLineLength < $lineLength) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $justifiedLineLength; $j++){
            if ($justifiedLineLength < $lineLength && $justifiedLine[$j] == " ") {
                $justifiedLine = substr_replace($justifiedLine, " ", $j, 0);
                $justifiedLineLength++;
                $j++;
            }
        }
    }
    $myTextJustified .= "$justifiedLine\n";
    $startOfLine += $originalLineLength + 1;
}
?>
<h3>Original Text:</h3>
<p><?php echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $myText); ?></p><br><br>
<h3>Justified Text:</h3>
<p><?php echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $myTextJustified); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But the text doesn't turn justified and both my paragraphs are completely same. Is this something to do with browser compatibility? Can anyone tell me? Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to justify the text by inserting spaces between words.

HTML is a language that specifies the structure of the document, not its formatting. By design, any program that renders HTML replaces a sequence of two or more white space characters (spaces, new lines, tabs) with a single space.

First of all, take a look at the source of your HTML document as it is received by the browser (use Ctrl-U or the Developer Tools command from the menu). This way you can check if your algorithm produces the outcome you expect.

In order to force the browser render the whitespaces as you want, a simple solution is to use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) instead. In HTML, a non-breaking space is encoded as `&npsp;`.

However, the non-breaking spaces, as their name says, do not allow the browser to break the line at that point (if needed).

Apart from your code being a programming exercise for the justification algorithm, in HTML (+CSS) the standard way to justify a text is to use the [`text-align: justify;`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-align) CSS property on the paragraph:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Had it not been for us whalemen, that
tract of land would this day perhaps
have been in as howling condition as the
coast of Labrador.</p>
```

This is how it works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNmMwQ